# How to draw the same Y-axis no matter what data is being plotted in R?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, axes

I have two multiple line graphs drawn in R using matplot().

The graphs are from the same time series data but showing two differing clusters. I want to draw the  y-axis so that it is identical in each plot I draw regardless of the data (range, max, min etc) that is used.

Could anybody suggest a means to achieve this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `ylim=` parameter? Without data or code we have no idea what you've done or tried.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. Ylim was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the ylim parameter should achieve what you are trying to do

```
plot_max <- 200
plot_min <- 0
plot1 <- matplot(data_set1, ylim = c(plot_min, plot_max)
plot2 <- matplot(data_set2, ylim = c(plot_min, plot_max)
```

This should get you what you want.